# CLS compliance issue in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, cls-compliant

What is not CLS compliant about the simple class below?

I get the warning that my derived class is not CLS compliant, because it inherits from the class below, which is not CLS compliant (apparently).

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseModel

    Protected MustOverride Sub SetIDValue(nValue As Long)

End Class
```

Yes - the above is the full code of the class.

Here are full files for both the base class and derived class:

#### Base class:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Namespace Core

    Public MustInherit Class BaseModel

        Protected MustOverride Sub SetIDValue(nValue As Long)

    End Class

End Namespace
```

#### Derived class:

```
Imports Snap.Core
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations


Public Class SystemValueModel
    Inherits BaseModel

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub


    Public ID_SystemValue As Long

    <Required()> <StringLength(25)>
    Public Token As String

    <Required()> <StringLength(255)>
    Public Value As String

    Protected Overrides Sub SetIDValue(nValue As Long)
        'Nada
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This bit of code is valid. I put in a basic console application with a derived class. Are you sure you are putting everything here that causes the error? How about the derived class? How do you know this is the bit that caused the problem?

Comment: Is this really the class, *as-is in your code*? I doubt it. There’s nothing which violates CLS compliance here.

Comment: Yes - that is the complete code. I pasted in the complete text of the file itself, for both base and derived classes. I get a compiler warning which says: "Warning 1 'SystemValueModel' is not CLS-compliant because it derives from 'BaseModel', which is not CLS-compliant.'

Comment: Taking the classes in a single Console Application it still perfectly builds... It is not the code that you post here that is the problem. There is something else causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and looking at it for me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this error by Enabling Code Analysis on Build and using "Microsoft All Rules".
To mark `BaseModel` as CLS Compliant, add `<Assembly: CLSCompliant(True)>` before `Namespace Core`  You can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182156(v=vs.120).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).